# get_map change colors and position

Tags: r, ggmap

My data frame looks like that:

```
Sho        lat     lon       autoroute
1000001 46.20114 5.19791         0
1000002 46.21842 5.22767         1
1000004 46.18836 5.24447         0
1000006 46.20754 5.23758         1
1000007 46.20105 5.24891         0
```

I have the next code:

```
basec=read.csv("map2.csv")
map <- get_map(location = 'France', zoom = 6)
mapPoints <- ggmap(map) +  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour=autoroute), data = basec, alpha = 0.5, size=0.8)
```

And the output is:

[image]

How can I change the change the colors of points depending on the route values? I've trying scale_colour_manual but I got the following error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

And as you can see at the top of the map of France appears slightly cut. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the color values change the variable to a factor:

```
basec$autoroute <- as.factor(basec$autoroute)
```

Also, you can center the map yourself. Use a different center

```
cntr <- c(2.645, 47.45)
map <- get_googlemap(center=cntr, zoom=6)
```

You can keep tweaking the center yourself if this one still crops a bit of the country.